# Why am I getting this null error? I'm trying to add to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having an issue adding to an ArrayList.
In my main method I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<Bin> warehouse = new ArrayList<Bin>();
    Bin a = new Bin( "A" );
    Bin b = new Bin( "B" );
    warehouse.add( a );
    warehouse.add( b );
    a.add( new BinItem( "1234-0", 500 ) );
    a.add( new BinItem( "1234-1", 25 ) );
    a.add( new BinItem( "1234-2", 7720 ) );
    b.add( new BinItem( "1234-3", 1000 ) );
    for ( Bin bn : warehouse )
        System.out.println( bn );
}
```

In the bin class there is:

```
private String myName;
private ArrayList<BinItem> myContents;
public Bin( String name )
{
    myName = name;
}

public String getName()
{
    return myName;
}

public ArrayList<BinItem> getContents()
{
    return myContents;
}

public void add( BinItem b )
{
    myContents.add(b);    //This is where I'm getting the error.
}

public String toString()
{
    String s = "Bin " + myName + ":\n";
    for ( BinItem b : myContents )
        s += b + "\n";
    return s;
}
```

It compiles fine, but whenever I run it, it says "java.lang.NullPointerException
" at the marked line. It's probably something stupid, but can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on it and check what the debugger says about `myContents` and `b`.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear you are initializing myContents anywhere

```
 myContents = new ArrayList<BinItem>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, it seems like you never initialize `myContents`:

`private ArrayList<BinItem> myContents;`

You should really always initialize it:

`private ArrayList<BinItem> myContents = new ArrayList<BinItem>();`

The best way to tell for sure is to set a breakpoint and run your debugger. Debugging is a very, very useful skill (and very easy to boot, in Eclipse).

It seems like `myContents` is null, not `b`.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark one of the answers as accepted (click the white-outlined check mark).

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because in the `toString()` method, you're trying to iterate through the `myContents` ArrayList, which has never been initialized for the majority of your items.